# Font not correctly displaying in Internet Explorer using the css property @font-face

Tags: css

I'm trying to render a font using the css property @font-face , in Firefox, Chrome and Opera it works fine, but within Internet Explorer is just does not want to display correctly, and reverts back to another standard font.

My code looks as follows

```
@font-face {

                font-family: "swatch";

        src: url("../../fonts/swatch.eot"); /* IE */

                src: url("../../fonts/swatch.ttf") format("truetype");

}

.header_text1{

    font-family: "swatch";

    font-size: 78px;

    text-align:center;

    color: #ffffff;

    padding-top: 50px;

}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Knu why? It's a valid CSS comment, isn't it?

Comment: @Roland are you 100% sure the eot file exists? Can you call it directly in your browser?

Comment: @pekka being valid isn't the problem here - wer talking about IE and removing comments helped me resolve issues previously

Comment: @Knu mmmkay... I've never heard of comments causing issues in any browser but it could well be.

Comment: @Roland what is the font called officially? Is it just "Swatch" or is it something like "Swatch Book ITC" or whatever? Try the most detailed name possible.

Comment: @All. It's called swatch it, and it can be obtained from http://www.dafont.com/swatch.font . I removed the comments and tried and no did not work, I then tried to open the eot file from the browser still nothing. I also can't use Cufon since this font can't be embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer, I developed this site on my local host and then it did not work, I then moved the site to the live server and that solved the problem. It probably was a caching issue. Thanks to all who tried to help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try without the quotes when you are using the font, font-family:swatch;